# Select an item, with an specific json property value, using as a dataset a list of objects with one property beeing a json

Tags: json.net, c#-6.0

I have the following list.

```
Public Class Car
{
  int id;
  string info;
}

List<Car> cars = {
  new Car(1, "[{'color': 'blue','model': 'toyota'}]"),
  new Car(2, "[{'color': 'red','model': 'tesla'}]"),
  new Car(3, "[{'color': 'green','model': 'honda'}]")
}
```

I want to return the id(3) of the Honda.

Do I need to convert the whole list to a Json, then query for the specific item.
Or can I do something like

```
var chosenCar =  cars.Where(s => JObject.Parse(s.info)["model"].Value == "honda");
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?  You wrote: *Or can I do something like* -- have you tried it?  Did it work?  It seems like it should.

Comment: Is `3` your expected output? Are there more than one "car" with the same "id"?

Comment: yes, 3. The id's are unique.

Comment: dbc, I tried, next is the error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and string

Comment: [`JToken.Value<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) is a method not a property, you need to do `JObject.Parse(s.info)["model"]?.Value<string>()`.  Alternatively you could the [explicit cast operator](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_28.htm) provided by Newtonsoft: `(string)JObject.Parse(s.info)["model"]`.